# JsonReader.Read() how to use it like StreamReader.Read()

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I have code in .NET CORE:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(InputStream); //ImputStream is NetworkStream
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

InputStream.Read() //For now i have this one because reader.Read() does not do what i want
Method method = new Method();
method = serializer.Deserialize<Method>(reader);
```

In my code, I have `InputStream.Read()` because the client sent JSON which looks like this: `[{'gg':'gg'}` and there is no `']'` meanwhile the client may do certain operations and then send `']'`.

Anyway I now have a problem in that the second iteration of the program (object Method can be replaced by another like LoginMethod etc.) because when I check `InputStream` I have correct new JSON which was sent by the client (checked it in wireshark), and in `reader` I still have the old one.

How can I force the `reader` to point to the same stream from `InputStream`? `reader.Read()` is not what I need here.

Comment: Have you tried waiting until your client provides full string or using inputStream.ReadToEnd()?

Comment: @Kirhgoph it is not what I need. I need somehow user `reader.Read()` like `InputStream.Read()`. The best solution would be if I'll find something like java's `reader.beginArray();`